# Android unable to write datetime to sqllite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

I'm using the Google Tasks API in my app. One of the fields in my app "due date" [requires a DateTime object](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks#resource-representations). Im using the Android datepicker dailog and an EditText view to capture the due date and then converting the user input into the datetime format. When I try to write to my SQLite database I get the following exception.

```
Error inserting due=2015-06-14T15:58:38.572-04:00 title=Test app _id=TaskId0.07429873487580996 status=needsAction notes=Test write
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table tasks has no column named due (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tasks(due,title,_id,status,notes) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

which is confusing because I do define a column named "due". Further up in the logs there is another exception.

```
06-14 15:58:38.607  15395-15395/com.github.idclark.forgetmenot E/EDITFRAGMENT﹕ null
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06/14/15" (at offset 8)
            at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
            at com.github.idclark.forgetmenot.EditFragment.getTaskDueDate(EditFragment.java:64)
```

The Schema is defined as

```
public static final class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tasks";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_UPDATED = "updated";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_SELFLINK = "selfLink";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_PARENT = "parent";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_POSITION = "position";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_NOTES = "notes";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_STATUS = "status";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_DUE = "due";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETED = "completed";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_DELETED = "deleted";
        public static final String COLUMN_TASK_HIDDEN = "hidden";
```

so the "due" column does exist. And the table is created by

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //status must be either needsAction or completed

        final String CREATE_TASK_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_ID + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_TITLE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETED + "TEXT, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NOTES + "TEXT, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_STATUS + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DUE + "DATETIME, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_UPDATED + "DATETIME, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_PARENT + "TEXT, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DELETED + "BOOLEAN, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_SELFLINK + "TEXT, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_POSITION + "TEXT, " +
                        TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_HIDDEN + "TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TASK_TABLE);
    }
```

The due date conversion takes place in this method.

```
public DateTime getTaskDueDate() {
    mDueDate = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.task_due_date);
    return new DateTime(mDueDate.getText().toString());
}
```

The data is then finally written to the database with

```
public boolean insertRow(Task task) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_STATUS, task.getStatus());
        values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_ID,task.getId());
        values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_TITLE,task.getTitle());
        values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DUE, task.getDue().toString());
        values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NOTES, task.getNotes());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        boolean createSuccessful = db.insert(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values) > 0;
        db.close();
        return createSuccessful;
    }
```

I'm confused as to why this write fails, and sql claims that there is no "due" column. Even though there is a parse exception, I see a timestamp in the logs as well. Is part of the problem that i'm calling `.toString()` on the datetime object before writing it to the db? I don't have a lot of sql experience and am genuinely confused as to what to make of these exceptions.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I was also thinking that calling toString() was a problem.

Comment: @burntsugar no still stuck, although i'm pretty sure it's a combination of the date parsing + adding the datetime entry to the ContentValues object

Comment: hrmmm, sqlite doesn't have a datetime type http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. i'll have to convert that timestamp to text

Comment: Your parsing error is tangential to the sqlite error. You're using the default SimpleDateFormat to parse your string, which uses the default format for your locale, which may not match the pattern of the date you're passing in. If you are always passing in month/day/year, you should explicitly set up your SimpleDateFormat by passing in "MM/dd/yy" as the pattern.

Comment: @joep i've updated the method to parse the date object into a DateTime object, however the exception is now `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time format: 06/15/15`. Any tips for formatting the date correctly?

Comment: @idclark You should ask a new question on stackoverflow that just deals with the date parsing question, since it's not related to your underlying sqlite question here.

Comment: @idclark As a quick guess though, I'd say do something like: new DateTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse(mDueDate.getText().toString()));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sqlite issue, you need to have whitespace between column names and types. For example, change

```
TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DUE + "DATETIME, " +
```

to

```
TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DUE + " DATETIME, " +
```

There's a similar problem with almost all of your columns.

After fixing the `CREATE TABLE` SQL, uninstall and reinstall your app to recreate the database.

For the date parsing problem, use a date format that matches your data. If you need detailed help with it, post a new question.

Comment: well that was embarrassingly simple fix